# Почему не отображается линия canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Все привет, хочу сделать сайт чтобы строить график линейной функции через canvas.

Самое простое что придумал вот:

```js
let k = +document.getElementById("k").value;
let b = +document.getElementById("b").value;
let x1 = +document.getElementById("x1").value;
let x2 = +document.getElementById("x2").value;

let posX1, posY1, posX2, posY2;

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas2d");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

context.fillStyle = "#e6f0d3";
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

// Рисуем ось X красным цветом
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(0, canvas.height / 2);
context.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height / 2);
context.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
context.stroke();

// Рисуем ось Y зелёным цветом
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(canvas.width / 2, 0);
context.lineTo(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height);
context.strokeStyle = '#00ff00';
context.stroke();

context.font = "8px Verdana";
context.strokeStyle = "black";

context.strokeText("(x:0;y:0)", canvas.width / 2 + 5, canvas.height / 2 + 10);

function drawGraph() {

  k = +document.getElementById("k").value;
  b = +document.getElementById("b").value;
  x1 = +document.getElementById("x1").value;
  x2 = +document.getElementById("x2").value;

  posY1 = k * x1 + b;
  posY2 = k * x2 + b;

  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(x1, posY1);
  context.lineTo(x2, posY2);

  context.strokeStyle = '#00ff00';
  context.stroke();
}
```

```html
<main id="app">
  <header>
    <h1>Построение графика линейной функции</h1>


  </header>

  <h3>Чтобы построить график функции вида - y = kx + b,<br>введите коэффициенты k и b ...</h3>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <form id="form">
    <input type="text" id="k" name="k" placeholder="введите k">
    <input type="text" id="b" name="b" placeholder="введите b"><br><br>
    <input type="text" id="x1" name="x1" placeholder="введите  x1">
    <input type="text" id="x2" name="x2" placeholder="введите  x2">



    <a type="button" name="submit" id="submit" onclick="drawGraph()">Построить график</a>
    <br>
    <br>

  </form>
  <div id="answer">
    <h3>Чтобы построить график линейной функции,<br> которым является прямая нужно минимум две точки.<br>Для этого возмем какие нибудь 2 значения x,<br>и посчитаем координаты по y ..</h3>
    <br>
    <h3>1 Точка:Пусть X1 = 3, тогда y = k3 + b,подставим наши значения получим координату Y для первой точки.</h3><br>
    <h3>2 Точка:Пусть X2 = -2, тогда y = -k2 + b,подставим наши значения получим координату Y для второй точки.</h3>
  </div>



  <canvas id="canvas2d" width="698" height="500"></canvas>


</main>
```

В общем пытаюсь получать координаты и коэффициенты из html input, преобразовать их в число и находить координату по y.

Функция `drawGraph()` выполняется по нажатию и в ней рисуется именно график функции, я уже поместил код где я присваиваю переменным значения из input прямо в функцию думал проблема в том, что он берет начальные (т.e никакие значения).

Кто нибудь может глянуть, что я делаю не так?

Comment: `что я делаю не так?` - 1. Не избавляете код от незначительных деталей. 2. Не добавляете в вопрос входные данные, что Вы вводите в поля?

Comment: а почему ты думаешь, что график функции не отображается? :)

Comment: @Grundy все отображается, только не там =)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ и я о том же :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом деле код работает. Просто не учтено два условия

1. координата (0,0) по умолчанию на находится в левом верхнем углу
2. масштаб 1:1 указывает на то, что одно деление соответствует 1px, то есть для точек с координатами `x` отличающимися на 2-3 единицы, построенную линию будет практически невозможно заметить.
3. не был поменян цвет рисования, а зеленый на данном фоне тяжело увидеть.

---

Для решения можно воспользоваться функциями canvas такими как:

1. [translate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/translate) - позволит переместить начало координат в нужную точку, в данном случае в середину canvas
2. [scale](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/scale) - позволит развернуть оси так, чтобы вертикальная ось была направлена вверх

В итоге может получиться следующий код:

```js
let k = +document.getElementById("k").value;
let b = +document.getElementById("b").value;
let x1 = +document.getElementById("x1").value;
let x2 = +document.getElementById("x2").value;

let posX1, posY1, posX2, posY2;

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas2d");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

context.fillStyle = "#e6f0d3";
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

// Рисуем ось X красным цветом
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(0, canvas.height / 2);
context.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height / 2);
context.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
context.stroke();

// Рисуем ось Y зелёным цветом
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(canvas.width / 2, 0);
context.lineTo(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height);
context.strokeStyle = '#00ff00';
context.stroke();

context.font = "8px Verdana";
context.strokeStyle = "black";

context.strokeText("(x:0;y:0)", canvas.width / 2 + 5, canvas.height / 2 + 10);

function drawGraph() {

  k = +document.getElementById("k").value;
  b = +document.getElementById("b").value;
  x1 = +document.getElementById("x1").value;
  x2 = +document.getElementById("x2").value;

  posY1 = k * x1 + b;
  posY2 = k * x2 + b;
  context.save();
  context.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
  context.scale(1, -1);

  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(x1, posY1);
  context.lineTo(x2, posY2);

  context.strokeStyle = '#0000ff';
  context.stroke();

  context.restore();
}
```

```html
<main id="app">
  <form id="form">
    <input type="text" id="k" name="k" placeholder="введите k" value="1">
    <input type="text" id="b" name="b" placeholder="введите b" value="0"><br>
    <input type="text" id="x1" name="x1" placeholder="введите  x1" value="-70">
    <input type="text" id="x2" name="x2" placeholder="введите  x2" value="70">
    <a type="button" name="submit" id="submit" onclick="drawGraph()">Построить график</a>
  </form>
  <canvas id="canvas2d" width="140" height="140"></canvas>
</main>
```

Comment: спасибо ,я понял что код работал,и сейчас понял что когда я пишу координату 1 и 2 то они проводит линию просто она очень маленькая так как для canvas 1 и 2 это растояние в 1 пиксель, а можно как нибудь тогда , чтобы было видно конкретно эту линию, мы же когда на листек рисуем , прямая бесконечная поэтому рисуем просто чтобы видно было где пересекает, так вот удобный вариант провести линию через эти уже имеющиеся две точки , только чтобы она продолжалась?

Comment: @SemyonDyachenko, ну формально можно масштабировать, либо вручную, когда результаты перед выводом просто умножаются не какое-то число, либо с помощью метода scale, который сейчас используется для разворота